# Searching a PDF file: using "AND Operator"

Tags: windows, pdf, adobe-acrobat, adobe-reader, pdf-reader

I was registering to the fall semester, my university offers a pdf, you pick what courses you want to take and register in on the website

[image]

I highlighted in yellow

- The subject (csc, computer science)
- THe course number
- The CRN

When registering, you need to know what course you want to take and what is the number of the course, you take the CRN and register it on the System.

Lets say i want to register for Discrete Methods. I can't just search for `csc` because that would show hundreds of computer science courses. I can't search just for the number, because maybe there's a business course with the number 211, or maybe there's a CRN that has 211. I cannot search for `csc 211` because the number of the course isn't directly next to the subject. Registering is a pain.

What I'm looking for the `And operator`, I believe it will do the job. Right now I am using Adobe reader on Windows, is there an adobe plugin that offers advanced searching options? Or is there another reader that does the job? (desktop app preferred, but if my only option is an online app, it's okay, free apps preferred, obviously)

Comment: This might be a solution: Either ask your faculty for an Excel file (and then you can filter the results) or try to convert your PDF to Excel using an online service like [this](http://www.freepdfconvert.com/pdf-excel). I've been able to search a similar tabled file simply by searching `CSC 211` (even if they are not directly next). Maybe it's the way the table is made that prevents you from doing this.